# Sending Multi Image from Flutter to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, dart

i am coding this new Ecommerce App where the user should add products, so i used Multi_Image_picker package where it let him choose multiple images and make them a List...

so i searched google how to convert this list to a file list and found a way i am using in my database code where i want to send all of this files to laravel backend:

```
     // String Prodcut Url/
  final productUrl =
      MyApp.defaultUrl + "/api/ecommerce/products/store?api_token=$token";

  // Get Dio
  var dio = Dio();
  try {
    List<MultipartFile> allMultiFiles = [];
    for (Asset asset in images) {
      ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();
      List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      var multipartFile = new MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        imageData,
        filename: basename(asset.name),
      );
      allMultiFiles.add(multipartFile);
    }

    var productData = FormData.fromMap({
      'store_id': storeId,
      'name': productName,
      'description': description,
      'category_id': categoryId,
      'price': price,
      'currency': currency,
      'is_discount': isDiscount,
      'images': allMultiFiles,
    });

    print(productData.files);

    var response = await dio.post(productUrl, data: productData);

    // Decoding The Request
    var responseArray = jsonDecode(response.data);

    print(responseArray);
      } catch (e) {
        // Returning error if exist
        print(e);
        return e;
      }
```

There is more code up there but for the space..

its giving me this reply

```
I/flutter (16670): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (16670): Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
I/flutter (16670): ^
```

welp my php code is:

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'store_id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'currency' => 'required',
        // 'images' => 'required',
    ]);
    $images_path = array();
    if ($request->file('images')) {
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $file) {
            $images_path[] = $file->store('public/uploads/products_images');
        }
    }
    $product = Products::create([
        'store_id' => $request->input('store_id'),
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'description' => $request->input('description'),
        'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'currency' => $request->input('currency'),
        'images' => json_encode($images_path),
        'is_discount' => $request->input('is_discount'),
    ]);

    return json_encode(['success' => $product]);
}
```

so if someone can help me to understand why this error is happening here